# Rendering `%` using element_markdown()

Tags: ggplot2, ggtext

How can I keep the `%` symbol in the title?

```r
library(ggtext)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("%") +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a space before and the character will display correctly.  Although there is a space, the formatting of the title will ignore this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle(" %") +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]